# Difference in manual execution of running app in background and runAppInBackground() using appium

Tags: appium

While executing `runAppInBackground()` for Android application through `Appium` the app gets restarted but when executed the same manually couldn't be able to reproduce the same. I Would like to deep dive into implementation of a `runAppInBackground()` method to reproduce the same issue in a manual way.

Answer (score 1):

You need to look behind the code of [runAppInBackground](https://github.com/appium/java-client/blob/master/src/main/java/io/appium/java_client/InteractsWithApps.java#L103)

From java client side (your test code) perspective, it is a [single call](https://github.com/appium/java-client/blob/master/src/main/java/io/appium/java_client/MobileCommand.java#L195) to Appium server:

`POST "/session/:sessionId/appium/app/background"`

If you continue looking into where its implemented on server side, you finish with **appium-android-driver** [function](https://github.com/appium/appium-android-driver/blob/master/lib/commands/general.js#L110).

In short what it does:

1. Get [current activity and package](https://github.com/appium/appium-android-driver/blob/master/lib/commands/general.js#L117)
2. Press physical [Home button](https://github.com/appium/appium-android-driver/blob/master/lib/commands/general.js#L118)
3. [Wait for time](https://github.com/appium/appium-android-driver/blob/master/lib/commands/general.js#L119) you provided as argument (seconds)
4. [Bring up back in focus](https://github.com/appium/appium-android-driver/blob/master/lib/commands/general.js#L122) based on different conditions; from the code you can understand what activity is being started

Basically its a sequence of adb shell commands, that you can run from terminal.

My guess is that step 4 you did manually may differ from what Appium is doing: different activities/arguments for activity been called